# Call WP plugin function in CodeIgniter controller

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I am using **WP Super Cache** plugin and wants to call `wp_cache_post_change( $post_id )` in CodeIgniter controller but I don't know I could I done it please help... :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved my problem. I just include exact file path where WP function existed & then call. :)